# YACC : symbol **** is used but, is not defined as a token and has no rules

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"
extern int yylval;
%}
%start E
%token number
%%
S   :E  {printf("%s",$1);}
    ;
E   :E PLUS T   {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    |T  {$$ = $1;}
    ;
T   :T STAR F   {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    |F  {$$ = $1;}
    ;
F   :LP E RP    {$$ = $2;}
    |number {$$ = $1;}
    ;
%%

yylex(){
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();

    switch(ch){
        case '+':
            return PLUS;
            break;
        case '*':
            return STAR;
            break;
        case '(':
            return LP;
            break;
        case ')':
            return RP;
            break;
        default:
            if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                ch -= '0';
                yylval = ch;;
                return (number);
            }
            else
                return -1;
    }
}

void main(){
    yyparse();
}
```

Afternoon, I was doing my assignment about how to use yacc and the thing is that I don't know how to properly include a header file on a .y file. From what I've seen to various pages which describes how to write a .y file, there is nothing I've done wrong about writing this .y file. So please, help me!

These are the error message I got

```
embedded@embedded-P15xEMx:~/Project/Compiler$ yacc parser.y
parser.y:19.10-11: error: symbol LP is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules
 F  :LP E RP    {$$ = $2;}
     ^^
parser.y:13.12-15: error: symbol PLUS is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules
 E  :E PLUS T   {$$ = $1 + $3;}
       ^^^^
parser.y:19.15-16: error: symbol RP is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules
 F  :LP E RP    {$$ = $2;}
          ^^
parser.y:16.12-15: error: symbol STAR is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules
 T  :T STAR F   {$$ = $1 * $3;}
       ^^^^
```

And this is the header file I included

```
#ifndef _PARSER_H_
#define _PARSER_H_

    #include <stdio.h>

    #define PLUS 1
    #define STAR 2
    #define LP 3
    #define RP 4
    #define number 5

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token symbols can't be declared by yourself, you have to use Yacc to do it, like

```
%token PLUS
```

etc.

Comment: Do you mean there should be a list of terminal symbols on the .y file even though they are already defined in the header file?

Comment: @user3551261 A token is a token is a token, it doesn't matter if it's a `+` or a `123`. And when you declare the tokens in Yacc, it will generate the token-symbols so they can be used from the C code, you should not define them yourself in the header file. In fact, I recommend you check the C source code that Yacc generates, you don't have to care about the tables or the state-machine code, but look at the definitions.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The point is on doing nothing about tokens!